# Using Requests library to achieve same result as Urllib (Pickle Module)

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests, pickle, urllib

New to python so give me a break if I've missed something stupid or it's been answered somewhere else.

Currently working through the ['Python Challenges'](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/). I'm on [challenge 5](http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/peak.html) and attempting to use the Pickle module through passing in some pickled text. I have got it working using the urllib as follows ...

```
import pickle
from urllib.request import urlopen

page = "http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/banner.p"
raw = urlopen(page)

pick = pickle.load(raw)

print(raw)
print(pick)
```

However, I'm trying to get it working with the requests library using

```
raw = requests.get(page).content
```

but when then passed into `pickle.load()`, I receive the error:

```
TypeError: file must have 'read' and 'readline' attributes
```

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It's my first answer on stackoverflow. I checked this 3 times lol
But yeah, this is in the requests doc itself.

```
import pickle
import requests

def main():
    r=requests.get('http://www.pythonchallenge.com/pc/def/banner.p',stream='True')    
    print(pickle.load(r.raw))    

if __name__=='__main__':    
    main()
```